# Should I return an NSMutableString in a method that returns NSString

Tags: objective-c

Ok, so I have a method that takes an `NSString` as input, does an operation on the contents of this string, and returns the processed string. So the declaration is:

```
- (NSString *) processString: (NSString *) str;
```

The question: should I just return the `NSMutableString` instance that I used as my "work" buffer, or should I create a new `NSString` around the mutable one, and return that?

So should I do this:

```
- (NSString *) processString: (NSString *) str
{
    NSMutableString *work = [NSMutableString stringWithString: str];
    // process 'work'
    return work;
}
```

Or this:

```
- (NSString *) processString: (NSString *) str
{
    NSMutableString *work = [NSMutableString stringWithString: str];
    // process 'work'
    return [NSString stringWithString: work]; // or [work stringValue]?
}
```

The second one makes another copy of the string I'm returning, unless `NSString` does smart things like copy-on-modify. But the first one is returning something the caller could, in theory, go and modify later. I don't care if they do that, since the string is theirs. But are there valid reasons for preferring the latter form over the former? And, is either `stringWithString` or `stringValue` preferred over the other?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depends entirely on how defensive you need to be.

There is no reasonable way a client of your code can test for mutability.  Thus, there is no reasonable way that a client can cast from `NSString` to `NSMutableString` and suddenly achieve no-compiler-warning mutability of the string.

So, as long as you trust your clients, you might as well return the mutable string (as an `NSString`).  Even if the client does something stupid and mutates it, compiler warnings be damned, nothing breaks.

Where it *does* matter is when you are returning the mutable backing store of some object that should not be mutated externally.  In that case, the client might ignore the compiler warnings and/or cast to the mutable variant and completely bork your object.

Or, more subtly, the client might grab a reference to the supposedly immutable return type and hold onto it long enough that it is mutated later, leaving their reference in a surprising state.

Best practice:  When computing and returning a transient value, mutability is irrelevant.  When returning a reference to an internal mutable store, best to make an immutable copy.